# How to document a type as just a name?

Tags: erlang, edoc

Looking at Erlang docs, sometimes I come across type specs, that document a function type without really specifying the type...

Hard to explain, so let me give you an [example](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:handle_call-3). In the `gen_server` the `handle_call` function shows up as the following in the docs:

```
Request = term()
From = {pid(),Tag}
State = term()
Result = {reply,Reply,NewState} | {reply,Reply,NewState,Timeout}
  | {reply,Reply,NewState,hibernate}
  | {noreply,NewState} | {noreply,NewState,Timeout}
  | {noreply,NewState,hibernate}
  | {stop,Reason,Reply,NewState} | {stop,Reason,NewState}
 Reply = term()
 NewState = term()
 Timeout = int()>=0 | infinity
 Reason = term()
```

Here the type `Tag` is never shown (i.e. it's just a variable name).

Is the same possible to do with `edoc`? The closest I found was opaque type spec, but that documents it as *abstract* - is that the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible as long as the argument variable name in the function (in all clauses) and that name used in the `@spec` are same. For example.

```
%% @spec start_link(Args) -> {ok, pid()}
start_link(Args) ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, Args, []).
```

will generate the following doc

```
start_link(Args) -> {ok, pid()}
```

If you have a different name for example

```
%% @spec start_link(Args) -> {ok, pid()}
start_link(Num) when is_integer(Num) ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [], []);
start_link(Args) ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, Args, []).
```

It would generate as

```
start_link(Num::Args) -> {ok, pid()}
```

assuming Args as a type.

I would personally not recommend to use edoc @spec and instead use -spec as they are used by dialyzer and hence can be validated.

edoc can generate the doc from -spec too. Given both -spec and @spec, edoc overrides to @spec directive.

```
%% @spec start_link(Args) -> {ok, Pid}
-spec start_link(term()) -> {ok, pid()}.
start_link(Args) ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, Args, []).
```

Above will result in

```
start_link(Args) -> {ok, Pid}
```

And removing @spec from above will result in

```
start_link(Args::term()) -> {ok, pid()}
```

Comment: Agree on recommending not to use edoc @spec and use -spec instead.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, this is not possible with Edoc.

I tried using a spec like this:

```
-spec foo(Something) -> term().
foo(X) ->
    X.
```

And while Edoc is actually happy about it, and gives the type spec as `foo(Something)` in the docs without specifying what `Something` is, the compiler complains about it, and says:

```
type variable 'Something' is only used once (is unbound)
```

So you'd have to write:

```
-spec foo(Something::_) -> term().
foo(X) ->
    X.
```

which shows up as `foo(Something::term())`, thereby giving a type specification for `Something`.

Using an Edoc-only type specification:

```
%% @spec foo(Something) -> term()
foo(X) ->
    X.
```

Edoc treats `Something` as a type name that applies to the variable `X` and puts `foo(X::Something)` in the documentation.

So neither way would do exactly what you want to achieve.